# Changing remote git repository

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have cloned a repo into my local folders and now I wanted to change my git repository to some other url. I have already changed it using

```
git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here
```

and when I am doing

```
git remote -v
```

it shows me the correct repository in which I want to work.But when I do

```
git branch --all
```

it shows me the old branches in the old repository. I am wondering why?? As my new repo doesn't have any branches yet.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way at all? Why not fork the original repo instead?

Comment: Does `git fetch -p` help?

Answer (score 1):

You are in fact seeing local copies of the old remote branches. You could use `git remote prune origin` to remove them. To be on the safe side, it's recommended you run `git remote prune origin --dry-run` first, just to see what exactly would be removed before removing it.

Answer (score 1):

The branches loaded in your repository are the old one anyway, since otherwise they would be lost.
If you do not need them (as you have done the upstream push to the new remote), follow these instructions to delete the old remote branches (watch out though: you should change back to the old remote, delete, and switch back again)
[How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely?rq=1)